# Don't reload the component on clicking browser's back button - Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, browser, reload, back-button

I'm working on a News website using Angular 8.x 
From Home page, when user scrolls down the page and clicks a news link, it takes the user to news details page. Now on clicking "browser's" back button, user comes to "Home" page, but the page is getting reloaded and scrolling to top.
How can I prevent the home page to reload on clicking "back" button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a service and when you get data from your api 1st time cache it in the service in a variable.

When next time news-list component reload it will check from the service variable. If not found, then api call otherwise get from service variable.

something like this.

```js
export class NewsService {
  newsList: News[];

  getSupportedBrowsers(): Observable < SupportedBrowser[] > {

    if (this.newsList) {
      return new Observable < News[] > ((subscriber: Subscriber < SupportedBrowser[] > ) => subscriber.next(this.newsList));
    }

    return this.http.get('url').map(response => {
      this.newsList = response.json();
      
      return this.newsList;
    });
  }
}
```